how to add a column to a dataframe that contains the sum by group
I wish to add a column to my existing data frame (sum_by) to a data frame, based on group sums, so that the points in each row are summed up within the column "group".
Have:
name <- c("Emma", "Joe", "Jack", "Eva", "Ann")
group <- c("a", "a", "b", "a", "c")
points <- c(5, 4, 6, 8, 9) 
df <- data.frame(name, group, points)

Expected:
name <- c("Emma", "Joe", "Jack", "Eva", "Ann")
group <- c("a", "a", "b", "a", "c")
points <- c(5, 4, 6, 8, 9)
sum_by <- c(19, 19, 6, 19, 9) 
df <- data.frame(name, group, points, sum_by)


Perhaps you want df <- data.frame(name, group, points); df <- df |> mutate(sum_by = sum(points), .by = group); df?

Your question is not clear. You already have sum_by. So, are you simply trying to add that vector sum_by as a new column to your data frame, or do you want to create a new column sum_by in the data frame as the product of a function as demonstrated by @stefan?

Perfect, thanks! My apologies, should have removed the sum_by from the 'have' because I don't have that.

If that is the case, then the suggestion of @stefan should work for you.
